# WP Rest API - Change response status code for failed validation request

Tags: rest-api, headers, validation

I have created a new route with this code:

```
register_rest_route(
    'namespace',
    'some-route',
        [
            'methods'             => WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE,
            'callback'            => 'some_callback',
            'args'                => [
                'description' => [ 'type' => 'string', 'required' => true ],
                'length' => [ 'type' => 'integer', 'required' => true ],
            ],
        ]
);
```

It uses a built-in data validation feature. Currently, when the validation fails it sends a response with some data and the status code `400`.

How to change the built-in validation response status to `406`?

Comment: One possible way is by using the [`rest_request_before_callbacks` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_request_before_callbacks/), but why do you want to use 406 instead of 400? Any specific reasons? Are you doing this just for your custom route or any other routes?

Comment: It's for custom routes. It's a requirement for a particular project. Nothing special.

Comment: Then as I pointed, you can use that filter to change the response's `status`, because I couldn't find a better/easier way to do it.